# Is there a pattern to pass parameter to another assembly?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

From a couple of my Assemblys like AssemblyA, AssemblyB, AssemblyC, AssemblyD I am calling a method in AssemblyE

for example:

```
DialogHelper.DisplayComments( param1,2,3,4) ;
```

now for some of those assemblies and not all of them I need to have an Overloaded version of DisplayComments() method that takes one more new parameter that I want to pass to:

```
DialogHelper.DisplayComments(param1,2,3,4,"5") ;
```

So one way is what I did: create an overload and pass the value.

But I was wondering if in .NET and Obeject-Oriented world is there any other elegant way of doing this so I can pass this value to that Assembly and that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OOP` world overloading is already *very elegant*.

If you want to try something else, can add [Optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), like for example

```
DialogHelper.DisplayComments(string param1, int prm2, int prm3, int prm4, string paramOtional="5") ;
```

Good luck

Comment: Please see my comment to Justin's answer about optional parameters.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: agree on this absolutely. Infact in my answer I suggest optinal paramater like an aletrnative. Overloading itself is already absolutely elegant in OOP.

Comment: I agree that overloading is the way to go.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: in any possible solution there is no single one that good for everything. There are always good and bad things.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the source code you better overload the `DisplayComments` method

otherwise (if they are not static methods) you can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that takes one more parameter

Comment: You can't create an extension method to replace a static method. Extension methods only work on instances. Furthermore, how should this help? What should the extension method do with the extra parameter?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Anyway if they are not static methods you can create an extension method for DialogHelper class.
Overloads is anyway the best thing to do

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword. Since you have mixed types (int and string), then you will have two options:

Use an object[]

```
public void DisplayComments(params object[] myVariableLengthParams)
```

Use a string param after the first 4 parameters:

```
public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, 
    int param4, params string[] myVariableStringParams)
```

OR, You could use defaults if you are using 4.0 (This might not be the best option if you are using a public facing API. It can leave things out of sync with expectations if the default changes, per Daniel Hilgarth's comment below.)

```
public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, 
    int param4, string param5 = "")
```

Finally, you could use overloads (however it seems that the `params` option might be best for you). And, this is pretty much the same as using defaults **if the logic is the same in both**

```
 public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4)
 {
     DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4, "");
 }

 public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4, 
     string param5)
 {
     //Final overload that does the logic
 }
```

**if the logic is not the same**

```
 public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4)
 {
     //Logic for 4 param
 }

 public void DisplayComments(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4, 
     string param5)
 {
     //Logic for 5 param
 }
```

You are allowed to have many methods with the same name as long as the method signatures are not the same (same order, same types, same return type)

Comment: Please refrain from using optional parameters in publicly facing APIs. The default value is compiled into the code of the calling assembly, not in the code the method is defined in. This will lead to hard to find bugs when you change the default value in your assembly, but don't recompile the calling assembly.

Comment: I think you should always prefer overloading

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I will move that option to the bottom and make a note as I do agree

Answer (score 1):

Try not to consider passing data to another assembly.  Instead focus on simply passing data between objects and methods.  What assembly those types are in shouldn't matter.  The way to think of `DialogHelper` is like a service.  It's providing a dialog to consumers which have separate needs.  Where they live is irrelevant, what they want is the important piece.

Here it seems like there is an optional extra comment parameter that some consumers need.  It is perfectly reasonable to provide this as an overloaded function or a single function with an optional parameter

```
public class DialogHelper {
  public static void DisplayComments(
    object param1, 
    int param2,  
    int param3,
    int param4,
    string param5 = "") {
    ...
  }
}
```